# How to solve Error starting ApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-07-07 12:52:59.026 ERROR 10816 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field authorDao in com.Jpa.Library.libraryItem.LibraryItemApplication required a bean of type 'com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.AuthorDao' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.AuthorDao' in your configuration.
```

Here's my code:

```
package com.Jpa.Library.libraryItem;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.AuthorDao;
import com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.LibraryItemDao;
import com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.RackDao;
import com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.RackItemDao;
import com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemEntity.LibraryItem;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryItemApplication implements ApplicationRunner{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LibraryItemApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private AuthorDao authorDao;

    @Autowired
    private LibraryItemDao libraryItemDao;

    @Autowired
    private RackDao rackDao;

    @Autowired
    private RackItemDao rackItemDao;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
    LibraryItem libraryitem = libraryItemDao.findByTitle("Fifty Shades of Gray");
    System.out.println(libraryitem);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Have a look at the [ask] link and try to add more 
additional information. What have you investigated so far for example. Explain also why this problem is JavaScript related.

Comment: Actually the error says it all : you have a bean that needs `com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.AuthorDao` as a dependency but a bean of type `com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.AuthorDao` could not be found in your ApplicationContext. Look closely at your bean configuration and investigate if you register bean of such type anywhere.

Comment: There's no code shown here that would cause the creation of the DAO beans you're looking to have injected.  Where's your JPA code that causes `AuthorDao`, `LibraryItemDao`, etc. to actually be created by Spring?  It seems likely that these objects are not being created as Spring beans, and there's no way for us to tell why from what you're showing here.

Comment: I'm really confused and I need more to know about my case., thank you

Answer (score 1):

A) Read error message carefully

B) "Consider defining a bean of type 'com.Jpa.Library.libraryItemDao.AuthorDao' in your configuration."

Answer (score 0):

< content moved to question by @Steve>

Comment: Please delete this answer and put all this in your question.  This isn't an answer to your question, so it doesn't belong here. - You can edit your question at will to add additional information.  That's the right move. - also, when you move it to your question, please try to be sure that all of your code formats correctly.

Answer (score 0):

**Please solve these two queries down below to get the solution:**

1. Have you annotated the `AuthorDao` class with `@Repository` ?
2. Have you given the **base package name** in `@ComponentScan` or in the **applicationContext.xml**? For example : `@ComponentScan("com.Jpa.Library")`**(for annotation based configuration)** or `<context:component-scan base-package="com.Jpa.Library" />` **(for XML based configuration)**

Hope this will solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Since it's a Spring Boot code , the component scanning will be done automatically because of the inclusion of @SpringBootApplication annotation.
2. When the scanning happens it will check all the components annotated with @Component annotation ,

So make sure your bean have that annotation . Also you can check this scanning by enabling the debug from application.properties .